# Where can I get RSS of MLB Standings syndicated? Not news, only standings

Tags: rss

I'd like to RSS the daily MLB standings. I've searched, but all the major sites seem to not RSS standings-- or anything for that matter. I use Sage feed reader within Firefox. I've only ever seen  it grab the Atom and rss2 formats.

Where can I get RSS of MLB Standings syndicated? Not news, only standings.

Comment: Voting to close because question is not about programming

Comment: Question is plenty about programming. Where or how can I make it grab the text daily? If there's not already a feed script out there... which seems there has to be somewhere.

Comment: Please read the help section. Asking for off-site resources is also off topic and the question didn't ask anything related to programming, only a link to a resource.